# How to resize the text area value dynamically using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need one help.i need to set text area value dynamically using Angular.js.
I am explaining my code below.

```
<textarea id="spec" name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Address" rows="4" style="height:73px" ng-model="address" readonly="readonly" ></textarea>
```

in the above text area i need to set the below values.

```
var address="USA";
var city="city1";
var pin="7521098"
```

the above value should display inside text area like below.

```
address:USA.
City:city1.
Pin:7521098
```

Comment: if you dont know angularjs then first try to study the documentation...dont start coding blindly...

Comment: Can you show us your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this
from the controller you can set the value of text area based on the value variables

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">      </script>
  <script>
    var app=angular.module("app",[]);
  app.controller("app_controller",function($scope){



   var address="USA";
   var city="city1";
   var pin="7521098"
  var address2="Address:"+address+"\n City:"+city+"\nPin:"+pin;
   $scope.address1=address2;
    });
 </script>
  <body ng-app="app">

 <div ng-controller="app_controller">

 <textarea id="spec" name="address"  placeholder="Add Address" rows="4"    style="height:73px" ng-model="address1" ></textarea>




  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Correct me if am wrong regarding the understanding of the question ??

Answer (score 0):

You are not using two-way-data-binding at all.

What you need is

```
$scope.address = "USA";
```

in your Controller. Then the variable will be binded to your text area.
But you want to display the whole properties inside the textarea.
Then you have to do something like:

```
$scope.textareaContent = address + city + pin;
```

And in your HTML

```
ngmodel="textareaContent"
```

// UPDATE

```
$scope.textareaContent = 'adress:' + address + '<br/>city:' + city + '<br/>pin:' + pin;
```

Comment: i know this but it will not come in proper format.Here i need all value with its header.